# MS Access query allows updates, but deleted records simply reappear after refresh

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a regular updatable query in MS Access. I can add and modify records, but I can not delete them. When I press delete, the window pops up and asks to confirm the deletion. I confirm and my query is updated with the record removed from my result set. Upon hitting "refresh" the deleted record reappears. The linked tables have "referential integrity with cascade delete and update" activated.

The following is the query:

```
SELECT tbl_process.processid,
       tbl_process.processname,
       tbl_process.topicid,
       tbl_process.sortorder,
       tbl_process.reviewerroleid,
       tbl_process.reviewerroleentityid,
       tbl_employee.employeename,
       tbl_process.active
FROM   tbl_process
       LEFT JOIN (tbl_employee
                  RIGHT JOIN tbl_reviewer
                          ON tbl_employee.employeeid = tbl_reviewer.employeeid)
              ON tbl_process.processid = tbl_reviewer.processid;
```

I have removed the `tbl_employee` from the query to see if that makes a difference, but it doesn't, the behavior remains unchanged. Only when I reduce the query to be a direct copy of `tbl_process` does it update and delete the record as it should.

**Why does Access not delete a record it claims to delete?**
Is this simply a bug or is there a logic to it?

**UPDATE**
I attempted to rewrite the query in order to avoid the problem. This is the rewritten SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl_process
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT tbl_employee.employeename,
                         tbl_reviewer.processid,
                         tbl_employee.employeename
                  FROM   tbl_employee
                         INNER JOIN tbl_reviewer
                                 ON tbl_employee.employeeid =
                                    tbl_reviewer.employeeid)
                                    AS tbl_B
              ON tbl_process.processid = tbl_B.processid;
```

The result remains the same. To me this now points to some fundamental issue within the architecture of the linked tables that Access is not handling.

Comment: Your DELETE process should grab the Process ID and only delete the record from tbl_Process where ProcessID = <the process ID of the record you're trying to delete>.

Comment: Should interact with data via forms, not directly with tables/queries. Deleting data should be a rare event. What are the relationships? If process is deleted, you want employees to delete? That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @June7 My users do interact with the data via forms, but since it didn't work properly, i broke it down to its most basic parts and began testing. The employee does not get deleted, only the record in tbl_reviewer (via cascade delete). The process makes sense from a business perspective.

Comment: @JohnnyBones I agree that this is what it should do, but for some reason it does not. I have tested further and discovered that the delete does actually trigger the cascade delete to the tbl_reviewer. The associated record there does get permenately deleted, but the main one in tbl_process does not.

Comment: I confirmed this behavior. I can't explain the logic. If you are using a form with this complex query as RecordSource, suggest you simplify. Should probably be using form/subform arrangement if not already.

Comment: @June7 I'm using this as a record source for a continous form, so subforms are out. I will attempt to gather the required EmployeeName via a subquery. I'll report back with that approach.

Comment: Review and consider https://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/Forms/Synchronize/LinkedSubforms.asp#:~:text=We%20synchronize%20the%20subforms%20using%20the%20Link%20Child,based%20on%20a%20control%20on%20the%20main%20form. Other possible options are DLookup and combobox for selecting reviewer has query joining tables as RowSource.

Comment: Redesigning the user form to account for this issue was too much work for what is essentially a finished application. I will post my own solution, but leave the question open and unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

Since no combination of changes that I tried yielded the necessary result, I ended up solving the issue by essentially "strong arming" the system.

I now delete the base record in tbl_Process via VBA that is located directly in the form.

```
Dim strSQL As String
Dim pID As Long
pID = Me.ProcessID
strSQL = "DELETE tbl_PROCESS.* FROM tbl_PROCESS WHERE tbl_PROCESS.ProcessID=" & pID & ";"
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
me.Requery
```

Comment: This is exactly what I suggested, and exactly what you should do.